# "graph neural networks" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-proposal

We have tags for convolution[conv-neural-network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conv-neural-network) and recurrent [rnn](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnn) networks, so I thought it might also be a good idea to have a [graph-neural-network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-neural-network) tag, since I've seen a fair number of such questions. At the moment, it seems that some people are using [graph-theory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) as a stand-in.

Comment: If you see a need, you may create the tag. If you do, please at least make an excerpt to help guide usage.

Comment: Makes sense to me. I think we'll start to see more of these questions in the future. I second gung's request to make an excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

The tag [graph-neural-network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-neural-network) has been created.